# A cheap(er) just-Internet connection in the Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, cost-of-living

When I moved in to my apartment I signed up with KPN for Internet access (over the telephone cabling, so some kind of DSL I guess) + a phone account (which I don't really use). I didn't compare prices much, I had other things on my mind.

Searching a bit right now, I mostly find "all-in-one" packages - Internet, TV channels and phone; and the packages are advertised for their extreme speed, another thing I don't care about.

How can I minimize my costs for a plain-vanilla just-Internet connection?

Note: I suppose this could depend on my place of residence. It's Amsterdam; and my apartment seems to have the coaxial cable connection used for "cable TV" (I mean I see a coaxial splitter sticking out from a wall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, most providers do have the option for only Internet, you might just need to dig a little deeper into their websites. You can use this site to compare prices between different providers.

> https://www.breedbandwinkel.nl/expats

Personally, I have a contract with XS4All and I can say that the speed I am getting is quite consistent with what is advertised.